# How can I create a copy of a virtualenv in pyenv?

Tags: python, pyenv

I used `pyenv` to create a virtualenv and activate it,

```
pyenv virtualenv myenv
pyenv activate myenv
```

then proceeded to perform a complicated and time-consuming installation of various Python packages in that virtual environment. Now I'd like to clone or duplicate or copy this virtualenv somehow, so that I can deactivate `myenv` and leave it untouched while I experiment with variations. Basically, I'm looking for something like

```
pyenv virtualenv-copy myenv myenv-copy
```

which I would use in a sequence such as, for example,

```
pyenv deactivate
pyenv virtualenv-copy myenv myenv-copy
pyenv activate myenv-copy
```

but nothing like `pyenv virtualenv-copy` seems to exist. What is the recommended approach for achieving this?

Comment: What if you used ‘pip freeze’ to save all of the packages and their versions?

Comment: why you don't use conda?

Comment: What OS are you using @Mhucka?

Comment: @jkr Doing `pip freeze > pip-freeze.txt` means you have to do a `pip install -r pip-freeze.txt` to install _everything_ again in a new virtualenv, and in my case, that's extremely time consuming. A pyenv virtualenv cloning solution, if it existed, would be much faster by bypassing the need to reinstall everything. (But `pip freeze` is what I have to do now, because I haven't found a better way.)

Comment: @AhmadAnis I don't see how the OS makes any difference, but anyway, it's macOS 10.15.

Comment: What I can think of is that you can copy the complete venv, and rename it. So venv are stored in `$(pyenv root)/versions` location so you can do a `cp $(pyenv root)/versions/yourenvname $(pyenvroot)/versions/envnewname`

Comment: i.e `cp -R /home/ahmad/.pyenv/versions/my-venv $(pyenv root)/versions/env2 ` Don't forget -R

Comment: @AhmadAnis I think you may be right – this looks promising. I will try this approach. Thanks! And now I see that in fact the OS does make a difference :-).

Comment: docker containers may be another approach.

Comment: @AhmadAnis I tested your approach (on macOS) and it seems to work without trouble. If you would like to post it as an answer, I'd be happy to upvote & accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create an environment in pyenv, it stores it in the directory `$(pyenv root)/versions/` Where `pyenv root` is the installation area of pyenv. On Ubuntu 20.04 for me, it is `/home/username/.pyenv`.

Now you can copy the env you want from the `versions` and give it a new name to have an exact copy of that env. So you can do

```
$ cp -R (pyenv root)/versions/old_env $(pyenv root)/versions/new_env
```

This will create a copy of `old_env` with the name `new_env`.

Comment: Worked for me.  You can also get a listing of environments to verify that the copy went well:  ```pyenv versions```